# How to enter the textfield.text in a special format

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have an app in which I want to enter first two charaters (Alphabets only)then space then next three characters numeric only,then space and next five characters numeric only again.

I know it has to be done in shouldchangecharacterinRange,textfield delegate method ,But what inside needs to be written is the real thing I am stuck on.I am a newbie in ios and not able to think about it right now.
What is the correct way to achieve it.Kindly give suggestions.Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the textfield delegate method [textfield shouldChangeCharacters replacementString][1]

[1]: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield ""

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code to implement whatever format you want in[`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield?language=objc) method. this method called everytime user edit (type/delete/paste) in your text field.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
//range: range of character to be replaced. 
  // string : will give you replacement string--mostly one chracter if user is //typing 
}
```

Comment: I know this but I actually need help in writing the code inside this method as I am too new to ios and not able to understand the things need to be done in it so that the desired format of textfield.text can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

this delegate will help you to check character that user enter depends you which you want to append or not in textfield
/********edit************/

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    if (range.length==1) {
        return YES;
    }



    if (textField.text.length<=12) {


        if ((range.location==0)||(range.location==1))
        {
            if([@"QWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM" containsString:[string uppercaseString]]){

                return YES;

            }
        }
        else if (range.location==2)
        {
            if ([@"0123456789" containsString:string ]) {
                string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",string];
                textField.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];
                return NO;
            }
            else{
                return NO;
            }

        }
        else if(range.location<=5)
        {
            if ([@"0123456789" containsString:string ]) {
                string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",string];
                return YES;
            }
            else{
                return NO;
            }
        }
        else if (range.location>=6)
        {
            if (range.location==6) {
                if ([@"0123456789" containsString:string ]) {
                    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",string];
                    textField.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];
                    return NO;
                }
            }
            else{
                if ([@"0123456789" containsString:string ]) {
                    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",string];
                    return YES;
                }
                else
                {
                    return NO;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this helps formatting the text while typing?

Comment: please Check updation in Ans

Comment: I already put this as answer, I simply didn't understand your first answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

  if (textField== YourtextField)

{
    if(range.length > 0)
         NSString *str = @"Abcdefghijkl";
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[str substringToIndex:2]];
}

  if (textField==YourtextField) {
    YourtextField.text = @"1234567890"
    int length = (int) YourtextField.text;

    if(length == 10)
    {
        if(range.length == 0)
            return NO;
    }

    if(length == 3)
    {
        NSString *num = YourtextField.text;
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) ",num];

        if(range.length > 0)
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:3]];
    }
    else if(length == 6)
    {
        NSString *num = textField.text;
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-",[num  substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];

        if(range.length > 0)
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
    }
}
return YES;
}
```